# SQL Server 2008 Stored procedure returning null for output value

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I can't get to the bottom of why my output variable in the code below is returning null. I've stepped through it in debug, and copy/ ran the sql statement, and it does return the expected values. But when I run it, just null. Any help would be great..

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCountOfMostRecentByTableName] @table VARCHAR(120),
    @count BIGINT OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @parameters NVARCHAR(100)
SET @parameters = '@count BIGINT OUTPUT'

DECLARE @date DATE = dbo.MostRecentTradeDateForDataDownload()

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'

SELECT COUNT(ID)
FROM ' + @table + 
' WHERE DateAdded = ''' + CAST(@date AS CHAR) + '''';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @parameters, @count = @count OUTPUT
SELECT @count

END
```

Comment: *shutter*. This type of procedure is ripe for SQL Injection.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks. I know it's far from best practices in a production environment, but this is a personal app residing on my local machine that will very likely stay that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't setting the @count variable anywhere.

Change

SELECT COUNT(ID)

to

SELECT @count = COUNT(ID)